# Is this a safe way to install simplejson for python 2.4 manually?

Tags: python, installation, simplejson

Mission: install simplejson(python2.4) to a chroot environment(no internet, no easy_install)

1. I download a simplejson library
2. unzip it
3. Do a `python setup.py install --prefix=my_chroot_path` finish, but not doc found.
4. I found there is a simplejson directory in the unzip directory, now I copy this to my chroot_path, I can use it.

Question: is step 4 effective????

Comment: You should use the code-indentation on SO for code only. Furthermore, what is your question? What do you mean by "effective"? What's not working?

Comment: I mean the installation method of simplejson. can I just copy it to one directory that in python ENVIRONMENT?

Answer (score 0):

You could <strike>either</strike> install it to a location which is in the pythonpath. Check the path via:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

(Depending on your OS, you can change the PYTHONPATH-Enviroment variable via command-line or other options).

<strike>Or (and this is the preferred method), just install it via `pip install simplejson`, which takes care of the dependecies, locations and stuff like that. It's even documented [here](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/1.2.1/). Check the *pip* installation instructions there as well.</strike>

**Edit**: Sorry, once there is no easy_install, you have to manually put simplejson in the pythonpath-folder, I guess.

Comment: ya, I just do that by step 4, I am not sure whether there are some difference between step3 and step4?